# css set border bottom on first 3 character of li when hover

Tags: css, hover, border

I want to set the border on the **first 3 letters** not only the first.

```css
li:hover::first-letter{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #759d00
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>School</li>
  <li>University</li>
  <li>Kindergarden</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:after` selector instead of `border` like this

```css
li:after {
  content:"";
  background: #759d00;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  display:block;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}
li:hover:after{
  display:block;
  width: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>School</li>
  <li>University</li>
  <li>Kindergarden</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works nicely for the example given but fails if the font-size is very different or the text has, say, many wide characters at the beginning.

Comment: Using `3em` will probably be a better option that a pixel value.

Comment: or even `3ch`...might be better

Comment: This is cool!! Perfect solution  
thank you

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way using just CSS of picking out the first 3 characters reliably (i.e. dealing with all font design possibilities and all font sizes and all combinations of characters) unless we put a pseudo element on each element with the first 3 characters of each as the content which seems messy.

If it is permissible to alter the HTML then something simpler like this will work - wrapping the first 3 characters in a span. You could do this at run time with JS if required.

```css
li:hover span{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #759d00
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Sch</span>ool</li>
  <li><span>Uni</span>versity</li>
  <li><span>Kin</span>dergarden</li>
</ul>
```